# Replace duplicate values with descending values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas df like below. (shape : 100 * 7)

I would like to replace the duplicate values, 
by keeping the first duplicate element and replace next duplicate values with valid numbers : Just a random values, but it should be in descending /reducing order.

E.g df =

```
index     DTI      ..........
0         117
1         117
2         117
3         117
4         106
5         106
6         103
.          .
.          .
11        92
12        92
13        91          ........
.         .
.         .
.         .
55        33
56        33
57        28
58        28
59        27
.
.
```

Required Df will be like : -

```
    index     DTI        ..........
    0         117
    1         115
    2         112
    3         110
    4         106
    5         104
    6         103
    .          .
    .          .
    11        92
    12        91.50            ................
    13        91
    .         .
    .         .
    .         .
    55        33
    56        30
    57        28
    58        27.5
    59        27             ............
    .
    .
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `replace next duplicate values with valid numbers`, under what criteria?

Comment: Just a random values, but it should be in descending /reducing order. 
(Say, in my example : take index 0 element, i.e 117, then replace the next vales randomly but in decreasing order till index 4 element 106) @yatu

Comment: Are the values in DTI always descending?

Comment: Yes always descending @yatu

Comment: Which am I missing? @mari

Comment: Since, in my question the index no 11, 12, 13 describes continuous values without missing values, **i want the decimal digit also to be added**. So after changing your answer to **float**, the requirement too satisfied @yatu

Comment: Oh in that case just remove `.astype(int)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the values in `DTI` are in descending order, one option is masking the [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) values, and using [`Series.interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html):

```
df.DTI = df.DTI.mask(df.duplicated(subset='DTI')).interpolate().astype(int)

    index  DTI
0      0  117
1      1  114
2      2  111
3      3  108
4      4  106
5      5  104
6      6  103
...
```